# How do I grep for multiple patterns on multiple lines?

Tags: grep

To be precise

```
Some text
begin
Some text goes here.
end
Some more text
```

and I want to extract entire block that starts from "begin" till "end"

with awk we can do like

```
awk '/begin/,/end/' text
```

how to do with `grep`? Are there any `grep` implementations on some *nix with which it can be done?

Comment: For such kind of operation better to use `sed` same with `awk`: `sed '/begin/,/end/! d' text`

Comment: Yes, with awk, sed it is possible. 
But that can't be done using grep?

Comment: @slm, what's the point of _closing_ the question for that reason? This question makes sense on both sites (askubuntu and here), a lot more so on unix.se

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - we have a specific close reason b/c cross-posting isn't allowed/tolerated. It's one thing if the Q was modified to conform to each site, but in this case it was a verbatim copy/paste. It's just not allowed. If the OP wants to close/delete the other Q's then it can be reopened. BTW, it was specifically flagged by others and I handled the flagging.

Comment: Thanks @slm, the question is still useful as it is. I've edited it to make it different from the AU one. When closing as multi-posted, it would make sense to add a link to the same question in other sites as people stumbling on this question would get frustrated by not knowing which site this question is potentially being answered on.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Sorry I'll do that in the future. The user that flagged it did include the link, but the UI is awful for copy/pasting info such as this from their comments in the mod tool, and I neglected to do so. I'll make sure to do that from now on.

Comment: don't crosspost http://askubuntu.com/questions/551338/how-do-i-grep-for-multiple-patterns-on-multiple-lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep`, that is `g/re/p` is a basic tool to **p**rint the lines that match a **r**egular **e**xpression.

You want more here like a **s**tream **ed**itor:

```
sed '/^begin$/,/^end$/!d'
```

or a more general text processing tool with an advanced language like `awk`, `perl`... as you already found out.

Having said that, some `grep` implementations can go a little further.

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)^begin$.*?^end$'
```

That's using the *multi-line* mode (`-M`); `(?s)` toggles the `s` flag in PCRE regexp so that `.` also matches newline characters.

With the current version of `pcregrep`, it's not guaranteed to work if the `begin` and `end` are more than 20kiB apart (or the specified buffer size).

For instance, it will match in

```
(seq 12091; echo begin; seq 4315; echo end; seq 10) |
   pcregrep -M '(?s)^begin$.*?^end$'
```

But not in:

```
(seq 12091; echo begin; seq 4316; echo end; seq 10) |
   pcregrep -M '(?s)^begin$.*?^end$'
```

Or with GNU `grep` built with PCRE support and assuming the file doesn't contain NUL characters:

```
grep -zoP  '(?ms)^begin$.*?^end$'
```

However that means that `grep` will load the entire file in memory before starting the search so should not be used except for small files. It also appends a NUL character to the output.

In any case, `grep` is *not* the right way to go here.